# Perl+Image::Magick usage: how to assemble several areas in one image into a new image?

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I'm new to ImageMagick and haven't figured out how to assemble several areas into a new image.
E.g., I know the "geometry" of words "hello" and "world" respectively in an image, what I need to do
is to retrieve the word images and put then into one line image while keep their relative positions.

Question1: Suppose I use the perl API, how should I use Composite() or other correct methods to do this?

```
my $geom = sprintf('%dx%x+%d+%d', $word->{width}, $word->{height}, $offsetx, $offsety); 
$x = $lineimg->Composite($wordimg, $geom); 
warn "$x" if "$x";
```

Suppose $lineimg's size is big enough to hold all word images and the geometry has been computed. 
This code gives out a complain by ImageMagick:

```
Exception 410: composite image required `Image::Magick' @ Magick.xs/XS_Image__Magick_Mogrify/7790 ...
```

Question2: currently I only know how to crop a word image out of the original one and then Clone() method
to restore the original image. Is there a way to copy instead of crop a specific area from a image? This way
can save the time to copy back and forth the whole image several times.

Does anybody know how to write this kind of processing? I appreciate all your help and suggestions!

-Jin

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around $x in `warn "$x" if "$x";`? There's no need to do that.

Comment: Stackoverflow lets you insert images into your question. That can help us see what you are starting with and what you want to end up with. And, as always, a minimal working program and the input that causes the problem is much more helpful than isolated snippets.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of things Image::Magick is not the right tool for your task.  Image::Magick is generally for manipulating entire image - filtering, scaling, converting between formats etc.

Consider the [GD module](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD-2.46/GD.pm), which can do just about any of the drawing operations you will need.